# How to configure WebDAV for always read-only access?

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

I've created an SVN repository and exposed it to the outside world using the WebDAV module in Apache (proxified through nginx), but I'm unsure how to make it read-only.

This is what my config currently looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:300>
        <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/svn/repos/dayz

                AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn.conf

                Satisfy any
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to commit however, SVN shows this:

[image]

I'm expecting to see a "not allowed" message instead. How do I configure this properly?

The repository will only be edited from within the server itself, so essentially I want WebDAV to only allow for directory listing and GET requests. Is it possible to do this without settings an anonymous user?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it for now by blocking any requests besides GET, OPTIONS, PROPFIND and REPORT.

Comment: Any documentation as to how you did that?

Comment: @Chris If I recall correctly, I simply configured nginx to reject other requests. It should be easy to find info about that in the documentation.